# .btn on hover changing background-color no matter what I do

Tags: css

I am using Bootstrap 3. I have a button, but I am unable to preserve background color of that button when I hover it. No matter what I do, its background color is always grey.

```
.my-btn {
    background-color: white;
    color: #2b526d;
    border-color: #2b526d;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.my-btn:hover {
    background-color: white!important;
    color: #dd3049;
    border-color: #dd3049;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

I want the background of my button to remain completely white.

Comment: Can you inspect the button, place it in a hover state and check the CSS that is being used? It could help trying to overwrite it if you know what is changing it.

Comment: @adr5240, thank you box-shadow: none; fixed everything.. I  did not even know I could set to hover.. life saving. You shoud post this as an answer and I will mark solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. But you can try the following css code. Hope it will work for you.

```
     .btn.my-btn:hover {
       background-color: white!important;
       color: #dd3049;
       border-color: #dd3049;
       opacity: 1 !important;
     }
```